# Rails controller/routing question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I am new to RoR and I cant get one of my rotes to work, not sure whats going on? I have defined a route in my routes.rb file, somthing like this...

```
map.connect 'myurl/:someid/:start/:limit', :conditions => { :method => :get }, :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'get_data_list'


# method defintion in mycontroller
def get_data_list (someid, start, limit)
   render :text => "Blah"
end
```

And I am using the following the url to invoke the above route and it does not work? Any clue?
http://host:port/myurl/24/1/10

It gives the following error. Looks its reached the controller action, but fails after that??

> Processing Mycontroller#get_data_list
>   (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-07-12 19:07:45)
>   [GET] Parameters: {"start"=>"1",
>   "limit"=>"10", "someid"=>"24"}
>
> **ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 3)):**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
map.connect 'myurl/:someid/:start/:limit', :conditions => { :method => :get }, :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'get_data_list'


# method defintion in mycontroller
def get_data_list
   someid = params[:someid]
   start = params[:start]
   limit = params[:limit]

   render :text => "Blah"
end
```

Comment: thanks :) i m java/php-CodeIgniter guy & in that world the path params are translated into method params. I guess RoR is different. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the (someid, start, limit) part of the method in your controller. Those variables are accesses by params[:someid], based on your route. The ArgumentError is because the controller method is expecting variables that aren't being passed to it.